# Universal Image Loader- Image can't be decoded-> .imageDecoder issue

Tags: android, android-studio, universal-image-loader

I get the error `E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded`. I found a solution here https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/539. One guy says to copy a class `NutraBaseImageDecoder` andd add `.imageDecoder(new NutraBaseImageDecoder(true))` to the options, but when I try to add this it doesn't recognize the `.imageDecoder`. What am I doing wrong ?

This is what I've tried:

```
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .imageDecoder(new NutraBaseImageDecoder(true))
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
```

The problem is with `.imageDecoder(new NutraBaseImageDecoder(true))`. There are no spaces in the url. I also have this in `Uri.decode(url)` when I'm passing it in the image loader.

Edit with errors :

```
    06-01 14:12:14.746  13047-14716/name.company.newproject I/System.out﹕ AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
06-01 14:12:14.766  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:14.766  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:14.766  13047-13454/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:14.826  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3151K, 17% free 21796K/26124K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
06-01 14:12:14.836  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:14.836  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:14.836  13047-13455/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:14.856  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 716K, 17% free 21817K/26124K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
06-01 14:12:14.926  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 15% free 22330K/26124K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
06-01 14:12:14.946  13047-13047/name.company.newproject D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
06-01 14:12:15.446  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.446  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.446  13047-13454/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:15.456  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.456  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.456  13047-13452/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:15.506  13047-13047/name.company.newproject D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
06-01 14:12:15.576  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.576  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.576  13047-13455/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:15.576  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.576  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.576  13047-13454/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:15.616  13047-13047/name.company.newproject D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
06-01 14:12:15.666  13047-13047/name.company.newproject D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
06-01 14:12:15.896  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.896  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.896  13047-13452/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:15.896  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.896  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:15.896  13047-13455/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:16.096  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.096  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.096  13047-13454/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:16.096  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.096  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.096  13047-13452/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:16.656  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.656  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.656  13047-13455/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:16.656  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.656  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.656  13047-13454/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:16.846  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.846  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.846  13047-13452/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:16.856  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.856  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:16.856  13047-13455/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:17.056  13047-13455/name.company.newproject D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4815K, 21% free 23079K/29068K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
06-01 14:12:17.316  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:17.316  13047-13454/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:17.316  13047-13454/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:17.316  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:17.316  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:17.316  13047-13452/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
06-01 14:12:18.116  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:18.116  13047-13452/name.company.newproject D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-01 14:12:18.116  13047-13452/name.company.newproject E/ImageLoader﹕ Image can't be decoded [httpURL]
```

The image is 2.6 MB.

Comment: What Exception u r getting ??

Comment: Does URL contains space ??

Comment: No. I lookes into that. It doesn't have any spaces

Comment: any solutions on this problem, still happen in Universal Image Loader??

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put `.imageDecoder(new NutraBaseImageDecoder(true))` with `DisplayImageOptions.Builder()` but with `ImageLoaderConfiguration` like :

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .imageDecoder(new NutraBaseImageDecoder(true))
            .writeDebugLogs()
            .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```